# How to get rid of "Object doesnot exists" error after resizing application window

Tags: testcomplete

I am working on a WPF application .These are some of the steps after which I am getting "object doesnot exists" error.

1.windowref= //reference of the window stored
2.Resize the window.
3.Close the application
4.Open the app
5.I then try to check if the resized window is still retained.
When I  try to access the windowref variable, its not able to locate the object.
I am using Testcomplete9 and scripting in jscript.

Thanks!

Comment: There can be different reasons for this error and it is impossible to understand which of them take place in your situation without details. Find more information in the http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/56626/ article. Also, you can contact the support team so they can help you with your specific situation (http://support.smartbear.com/message/?prod=TestComplete).

Comment: Got the issue resolved.I had to use the method  Terminate() to kill the application.Even though i had checks in my script to make sure that the application is closed somehow it seems there were old instances of the application.